# Weird Obtics Exception

Tags: wpf, linq, mvvm, viewmodel, inotifypropertychanged

I am using Obtics library for my live-linq queries.

But I can't get pass this weird exception which makes no sense at all.

Here is my query:

```
var query = ExpressionObserver.Execute(() =>
        from o in _orders.DefaultIfEmpty(new OrderStatusViewModel())
        where o.State != OrderStateEnum.Canceled
        group o by o.Isin
            into g
            let name = _referenceData.GetInstrumentName(g.Key)
            orderby name ascending
            select new ComplexRowViewModel(_referenceData)
            {
                UnderlyingOrder = g.First(),
                PrimaryExchange = (from q in _quotes.DefaultIfEmpty(new QuoteTickViewModel()).Where(w => w.Exchange == _referenceData.GetPrimaryExchangeId(g.Key) && w.Isin == g.Key && w.Provider == ProviderEnum.Bloomberg)
                                   select new SimpleRowViewModel()
                                   {
                                       UnderlyingQuote = q
                                   }).First(),
                Groupped = (from y in _orders.DefaultIfEmpty(new OrderStatusViewModel())
                            join x in _quotes.DefaultIfEmpty(new QuoteTickViewModel()) on new { y.Isin, y.Exchange }
                                equals new { x.Isin, x.Exchange }
                            where
                                y.Isin == g.Key &&
                                y.State != OrderStateEnum.Canceled &&
                                x.Provider == ProviderEnum.Tradebase &&
                                x.Exchange !=
                                _referenceData.GetPrimaryExchangeId(g.Key)
                            group x by new { x.Exchange }
                                into p
                                select new SimpleRowViewModel()
                                {
                                    UnderlyingQuote = p.First()
                                }
                           ),
                Uncompressed = (from o in _orders.DefaultIfEmpty(new OrderStatusViewModel())
                                where o.State != OrderStateEnum.Canceled && o.Isin == g.Key
                                select new UncompressedRowViewModel() { UnderlyingOrder = o }),

                Compressed = (from o in _orders.DefaultIfEmpty(new OrderStatusViewModel())
                              where o.State != OrderStateEnum.Canceled && o.Isin == g.Key
                              group o by new { o.LimitPrice, o.OrderSide } into x
                              select new CompressedRowViewModel()
                              {
                                  Ask = x.Key.OrderSide == OrderSideEnum.Sell ? (decimal?)x.Key.LimitPrice : (decimal?)null,
                                  AskSize = x.Key.OrderSide == OrderSideEnum.Sell ? x.Select(s => s.Quantity).Aggregate((c, n) => c + n) : 0,
                                  Bid = x.Key.OrderSide == OrderSideEnum.Buy ? (decimal?)x.Key.LimitPrice : (decimal?)null,
                                  BidSize = x.Key.OrderSide == OrderSideEnum.Buy ? x.Select(s => s.Quantity).Aggregate((c, n) => c + n) : 0,
                                  Exchange = string.Join(", ", x.Select(s => s.Exchange)),
                                  Isin = x.First().Isin.ToString(),
                                  OrderBuyCount = x.Key.OrderSide == OrderSideEnum.Buy ? x.Count() : 0,
                                  OrderSellCount = x.Key.OrderSide == OrderSideEnum.Sell ? x.Count() : 0,
                                  RowSide = x.Key.OrderSide == OrderSideEnum.Sell ? RowSide.Sell : RowSide.Buy
                              })}
    ).Cascade();

GridData = query;
```

I uploaded the class which makes all this possible. http://www.4shared.com/file/ce_V8PPh/MarketData.html

The exception is:

```
InvalidOperationException, Added item does not appear at given index '0'.
```

But this makes no sense since the item is already there.

Everything works fine until an OrderStatus gets a "Cancelled" state. I think it is because I filter the cancelled orders on top of the query, but how is this relevant I don't know.

Comment: How about making it more readable first?

Comment: I tend to recommend against file sharing sites, since they post security risks, and often they are a fiddle to download from. Use pastie.org or Github Gists (etc) if you can `:)`

Comment: Richard, sorry to rollback: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/weird

Comment: You need to break this query up into separate parts in order to determine which part causes the exception.

Comment: I've not used this at all, but is there a stack trace for this sort of thing? Such a thing might contain details about where your error is.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution to my problem. It turns out that Obtics has a problem with on the fly class creation with lambda, such as

```
from o in orders where o.state == "active" select new OrderModel2 {Underlying = o}
```

new keyword messes all up. you need handle this class creation manually.

Anyways after 2 days of head smashing I ended up having this much code.

```
private void CreateQueries()
{
    var query = ExpressionObserver.Execute(() => (from o in _orders
                                                  where o.State != OrderStateEnum.Canceled
                                                  group o by o.Isin
                                                      into g
                                                      let name = _referenceData.GetInstrumentName(g.Key)
                                                      orderby name ascending
                                                      select GetComplexRowViewModel(
                                                                                    g.First()
                                                                                    ,
                                                                                    (from p in _quotes
                                                                                     where
                                                                                         p.Isin == g.Key &&
                                                                                         p.Exchange == _referenceData.GetPrimaryExchangeId(g.Key) &&
                                                                                         p.Provider == ProviderEnum.Bloomberg
                                                                                     select GetSimpleRowViewModel(p))
                                                                                     ,
                                                                                     (from q in _quotes
                                                                                      where
                                                                                          q.Isin == g.Key &&
                                                                                          q.Provider == ProviderEnum.Tradebase &&
                                                                                          g.Select(s => s.Exchange).Contains(q.Exchange)
                                                                                      select GetSimpleRowViewModel(q))
                                                                                      ,
                                                                                      (from o in _orders
                                                                                       where o.Isin == g.Key
                                                                                       && o.State != OrderStateEnum.Canceled
                                                                                       group o by new { o.LimitPrice, o.OrderSide } into x
                                                                                       select GetCompressedRowViewModel
                                                                                       (
                                                                                           x.Key.OrderSide == OrderSideEnum.Sell ? (decimal?)x.Key.LimitPrice : (decimal?)null,
                                                                                           x.Key.OrderSide == OrderSideEnum.Sell ? x.Select(s => s.Quantity).Aggregate((c, n) => c + n) : 0,
                                                                                           x.Key.OrderSide == OrderSideEnum.Buy ? (decimal?)x.Key.LimitPrice : (decimal?)null,
                                                                                           x.Key.OrderSide == OrderSideEnum.Buy ? x.Select(s => s.Quantity).Aggregate((c, n) => c + n) : 0,
                                                                                           string.Join(", ", x.Select(s => s.Exchange)),
                                                                                           x.First().Isin.ToString(),
                                                                                           x.Key.OrderSide == OrderSideEnum.Buy ? x.Count() : 0,
                                                                                           x.Key.OrderSide == OrderSideEnum.Sell ? x.Count() : 0,
                                                                                           x.Key.OrderSide == OrderSideEnum.Sell ? RowSide.Sell : RowSide.Buy
                                                                                       ))
                                                           ,
                                                           (from o in _orders
                                                            where o.Isin == g.Key
                                                            && o.State != OrderStateEnum.Canceled
                                                            select GetUncompressedRowViewModel(o))

                                                                                     ))).Cascade();
    GridData = query;
}


// Obtics 
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, ComplexRowViewModel> _complexRowViewModels = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ComplexRowViewModel>();
private ComplexRowViewModel GetComplexRowViewModel(OrderStatusViewModel model, IEnumerable<SimpleRowViewModel> primaryExchanges, IEnumerable<SimpleRowViewModel> groupped
    , IEnumerable<CompressedRowViewModel> compressed, IEnumerable<UncompressedRowViewModel> uncompressed)
{
    if (model == null)
        return _complexRowViewModels.GetOrAdd("", s2 => new ComplexRowViewModel());

    return _complexRowViewModels.GetOrAdd(model.Isin,
                                          s2 =>
                                          new ComplexRowViewModel(_referenceData) { UnderlyingOrder = model, PrimaryExchange = primaryExchanges.DefaultIfEmpty(new SimpleRowViewModel()).First(), Groupped = groupped, Compressed = compressed, Uncompressed = uncompressed });
}

private ConcurrentDictionary<string, SimpleRowViewModel> _simpleRowViewModels = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, SimpleRowViewModel>();
private SimpleRowViewModel GetSimpleRowViewModel(QuoteTickViewModel model)
{
    if (model == null)
        return _simpleRowViewModels.GetOrAdd("", s2 => new SimpleRowViewModel());

    return _simpleRowViewModels.GetOrAdd(model.Isin + model.Exchange,
                                                        s2 =>
                                                        new SimpleRowViewModel() { UnderlyingQuote = model });
}

private ConcurrentDictionary<string, UncompressedRowViewModel> _uncompressedRowViewModels = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, UncompressedRowViewModel>();
private UncompressedRowViewModel GetUncompressedRowViewModel(OrderStatusViewModel model)
{
    if (model == null)
        return _uncompressedRowViewModels.GetOrAdd("", s2 => new UncompressedRowViewModel());

    return _uncompressedRowViewModels.GetOrAdd(model.InternalId,
                                                        s2 =>
                                                        new UncompressedRowViewModel() { UnderlyingOrder = model });
}

private ConcurrentDictionary<string, CompressedRowViewModel> _compressedRowViewModels = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, CompressedRowViewModel>();
private CompressedRowViewModel GetCompressedRowViewModel(decimal? Ask, int AskSize, decimal? Bid, int BidSize, string Exchange, string Isin, int OrderBuyCount, int OrderSellCount, RowSide RowSide)
{

    return new CompressedRowViewModel()
               {
                   Ask = Ask,
                   AskSize = AskSize,
                   Bid = Bid,
                   BidSize = BidSize,
                   Exchange = Exchange,
                   Isin = Isin,
                   OrderBuyCount = OrderBuyCount,
                   OrderSellCount = OrderSellCount,
                   RowSide = RowSide
               };
}
```

It works but looks ugly, if anyone has a way to make it more beautiful I'll be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the 'new' keyword but rather that two instances of type OrderModel2 are not equal even though they are created with equal construction arguments.

This can be solved in three ways:

1. Override the Equals method of your object.
2. Apply an ObticsEqualityComparerAttribute to your class with the specific equality comparer for Obtics to use.
3. Create a factory with a repository that returns the same object instance when called with the same construction arguments.

You seem to have used number 3, though I think your code could be more simple and generic.